# Filter Twitter API GET user/show results

Tags: php, api, twitter

I'm using a PHP wrapper for my Twitter API calls which is found [here](https://github.com/J7mbo/twitter-api-php).

I'm trying to get a follower count for my account and I am using

```
$url = 'https://api.twitter.com/1.1/users/show.json';
$getfield = '?screen_name=symphaticidiot';
$requestMethod = 'GET';

$twitter = new TwitterAPIExchange($settings);
$response = $twitter->setGetfield($getfield)
                ->buildOauth($url, $requestMethod)
                ->performRequest();

var_dump(json_decode($response));
```

This works and does display the information. How do I filter it so it will only display `follower_count` instead of

```
object(stdClass)#2 (43) { ["id"]=> int(391356688) ["id_str"]=> string(9) "391356688"                                         ["name"]=> string(8) "It's Dom" ["screen_name"]=> string(14) "symphaticidiot" ["location"]=> string(13) "Hull, England" ["description"]=> string(110) "Specialised Generalist, #webguy, #poet, #IT Techie and the guy who has @amb_freeman as his amazing girlfriend." ["url"]=> string(22) "http://t.co/YSoqD2K0NZ" ["entities"]=> object(stdClass)#3 (2) { ["url"]=> object(stdClass)#4 (1) .....
```

Comment: You mean `echo $response[key]`?

Comment: I tried using `$response['followers_count']` and all I got back was a `{`

Comment: Can you post the dump of `$response`?

Comment: Hi Chris, cheers for the help. I've just managed to find it out. To access the `key` within the json object, you use `$response->KEY` instead of `$response[KEY].`

Comment: Of course! Can't believe I missed that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it working using the following code

```
$url = 'https://api.twitter.com/1.1/users/show.json';
$getfield = '?screen_name=symphaticidiot';
$requestMethod = 'GET';

$twitter = new TwitterAPIExchange($settings);
$response = $twitter->setGetfield($getfield)
                    ->buildOauth($url, $requestMethod)
                    ->performRequest();

$json_output = json_decode($response);

$followers = $json_output->followers_count
```